Next js typescript conditionally export a module
In Next.js (v.15 w/ App Router) i have 2 modules of server actions where i export the same functions, each with a different database, like so :
--> databases/mongodb/server_actions
...all the necessary imports, "use server" declaration, etc

export interface IActionState {
  success: string | null
  error: string | null
}

const createWallet = async (
  previousState: IActionState,
  formData: FormData
): Promise<IActionState> => {
  try {
    const session = await auth()
    await connectDB()
    const title = formData.get("title") as string
    const user = session?.user?.email as string

    const wallet = new WalletModel({ title, user })
    await wallet.save()
    //await new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, 1000)) // Simulate slow network
    return { success: `Wallet ${title} created successfully`, error: null }
  } catch (error: any) {
    //await new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, 1000)) // Simulate slow network
    return { success: null, error: error?.message || "An error occurred" }
  }
}


export {
  createWallet,
  //and some others
}

the other one is databases/postgres/server_actions with the same logic
How can i create a third module, which only responsibility would be to determine which one to expose to the consumer component ?
I have tried something like :
--> dbActionsRouter.ts
const DATABASE = process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_DATABASE

let moduleToExport: any

if (DATABASE === "MONGODB") {
  moduleToExport = await import("@/databases/mongodb/server_actions")
} else if (DATABASE === "POSTGRES") {
  moduleToExport = await import("@/databases/postgres/server_actions")
} else {
  throw new Error("DATABASE environment variable is not set or is invalid")
}

console.log(`Using ${DATABASE} database`)
console.log(`Using ${moduleToExport} as database actions`)

export default moduleToExport


But when i try to import it at a client component
import { createWallet } from "@/dbActionsRouter"

i get

module '"@/dbActionsRouter"' has no exported member 'createWallet'

and after running it at :
...
<form action={action}>
...



Unhandled Runtime Error
TypeError: action is not a function

and these 2 console warnings :

./app/create_wallet/NewWalletForm.client.tsx
Attempted import error: 'createWallet' is not exported from '@/dbActionsRouter' (imported as 'createWallet').

and

./dbActionsRouter.ts
The generated code contains 'async/await' because this module is using "topLevelAwait".
However, your target environment does not appear to support 'async/await'.
As a result, the code may not run as expected or may cause runtime errors.

Also is this the correct way to have multiple databases ready to be used ?
Im trying to make it as simple and readable as possible instead of checking the env variable at every action and run the operation in a different db every time

But why to do so? Exchanging Mongo and Postgres like socks doesn't seem like a good idea to me.

I just want to familiarize myself in both

What about exporting a createWallet that either returns the result of the mongo one or the postgres one depending on that environment variable?
